# Is possible to add the icon in material UI date picker?

Tags: android, datepicker, material-ui

I try to use the date picker sample from material io
https://material.io/develop/android/components/picker
But seem no any method to add icon to the inside calender,  anyone have idea?

Comment: Where do you want to put the icon?

Comment: In the calender screen,  for example,  I want to add icon inside the calender,  let user aware the date categorize to some event,  do u have idea?